# Playing of videos in Chromium in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, video, chromium

I can't play any video at Dailymotion in Chromium web browser in Ubuntu 16.04. The warning says `Whoops! Looks like we can't play this video in this browser`. Also the videos from Facebook and Twitter are not being played -- there it says "couldn't load plug-in" / "The media could not be played". I have tried many solutions available on the web, but nothing is working.

Results of running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`

```
:~$ sudo apt-get update  
Err:11 ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages 404 Not Found 
E: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mai‌​n/… 404 Not Found 
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. 

:~$ sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
adobe-flashplugin is already the newest version (1:20170411.1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1). 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed. 
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ... 
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: 
Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused  
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):   
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 
Errors were encountered while processing: runit 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Yes, I did and the outputs are the following:

Comment: 1. $ sudo apt-get update
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/skunk/pepper-flash/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: 2. $ sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
adobe-flashplugin is already the newest version (1:20170411.1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.

Comment: After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `pepper-flash` ppa shouldn't necessary to ensure flash working on Chromium (CMIIW), moreover that ppa is outdated and doesn't have release file for 16.04 (Xenial). Thus making the ppa cannot be used.

Simply installing `adobe-flashplugin` package would get the job done:

1. Enable canonical partner, run following command one-by-one:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install `adobe-flashplugin` then:

   ```
   sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
   ```

Also, for that `runit` problem, its most likely was a bug and has been reported to launchpad. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/runit/+bug/1448164